# Correct way to setup cell only once with a reusable cell?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, swift3

I'm looking for the correct way to work with a reusable cell in Swift.

How can I make the `setup` method to be called only once?

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.tableView.register(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "AwesomeCell")
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = self.tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "AwesomeCell") as UITableViewCell? ?? UITableViewCell()
    self.setup(cell: cell)  // I want this to be called only once
    cell.textLabel?.text = self.data[indexPath.row]
    return cell
}

func setup(cell: UITableViewCell) {
    cell.accessoryType = .disclosureIndicator
}
```

Thank you.

Comment: just curious, why do you need to do it in a separate function though? wouldn't cell.accessoryType = .disclosureIndicator if you dont always want to set why not check if the cell's accessoryType is already a disclosureIndicator before setting it? and if it gets complicated why not just subclass a UITableViewCell and do the proper setup on that?

Comment: @Joshua it's just an example.

Comment: then the best way I can see will be subclassing and do the setup on the init

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you register your cell with class, then you should put it in `init(style:reuseIdentifier:)` initializer of your cell. When you call `dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier:for:)`, that is the initializer that gets called it the table view cant reuse it yet.

If you registered cell with Xib, use cell's `init(coder:)`

Comment: If I understand you correctly, the best approach is to create a custom cell class and in it's init do the setup, then register that custom cell?

Comment: Yes. If you don't need to do anything else with the cell, you may only override the appropriate initializer and do the setup.

Answer (score -1):

In class `UITableViewCell` .Try this:

```
  override func awakeFromNib() {
       super.awakeFromNib()
       self.accessoryType = .disclosureIndicator
  }
```

If you want to create a cell on the storyboard or xib. You can go to the accessory property and select Disclosure Indicator

[image]

Comment: Any class of UITableViewCell has awakeFromNib ()

Comment: Yes, but if cell was created purely in code, without Xib or Storyboard, then obviously it will not call `awakeFromNib`

Comment: if cell was created on storyboard or xib. You can set the accessory property and select disclosureIndicator

Comment: The .disclosureIndicator is just an example, what if I want to do more "complex" stuff during cell setup?